# Orbeon forms - repeated section field validation

Tags: orbeon

I have form like this: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/f34f17613d9dbce14bcdf1219b1a7a6babaeebe2

I want to add validation like this:

- only one field 'yes/no' in this section can have selected value 'yes' at the same time
- validation message should appear only under the fields with selected value 'yes'

Should I create some action, that iterate over all 'yes/no' fields, check their value and raise an error if detect above situation?

My main problem is how to iterate over all 'yes/no' fields and detect this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you name your field `yes-no`, then the following expression will do it:

```
string() = 'false' or
count(//yes-no[string() = 'true']) <= 1
```

With this expression you're saying that an answer is valid if either:

- it is "No", as we don't have any limit on those, or
- there only one "Yes", or less.

And for more on that `string() = 'true'` business, see [Testing on a Yes No Answer field](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas/formulas-examples#testing-on-a-yes-no-answer-field).

[image: At most one Yes]

Comment: Thanks @avernet. It works very well. I have added small improvement for the situation, when user don't select anything yet. 
`string() = 'false' or string() = '' or count(//yes-no[string() = 'true']) <= 1`

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad that works, and that you got a hang of it! ‑Alex